# Getting into a yarn dev 'category'?

Tags: yarnpkg, yarnpkg-v2

A Yarn Getting Started [Recipe](https://yarnpkg.com/getting-started/recipes#typescript--pnp-quick-start) tells me how to install Typescript using yarn:

`yarn add --dev typescript`

But when I then type, for example, `tcs app.ts` for typescript to compile my `app.ts` file I get the error

> zsh: command not found: tcs

How do I get into the `dev` 'category', which I specified in `yarn add` ([docs](https://yarnpkg.com/cli/add))?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command is actually `tsc`. If typescript is installed locally, you run it by `yarn tsc`.

'dev' is not a 'category', it's a kind of dependency: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/configuring-npm/package-json#devdependencies - only used when developing, in opposite to production where you may use `yarn install --production` because there's no need for typescript anymore. Only packages from https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/configuring-npm/package-json#dependencies are installed then.